# Powershell not getting the write variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-3.0

so i'm new to powershell and i'm training  myself by doing my first script with a menu, and from time to time i'm adding stuff to understand and learn new things

so now i have a question, when the user is asked to input a choice, let say number 1, he then will get asked to input a number of pc's that will be pinged

i'me tring to get something like "if the pc is alive" the user will get answer "the pc is alive"

here is the code:

```
$mypc = read-host -prompt "what is the name of the pc?"

Test-Connection -ComputerName $mypc -Count 1

if ($mypc = $true) {

write-host "the $mypc is alive"

}
```

and i'm not getting the right answer

this is what i'm getting after successful "test-connection"

```
the True is alive
```

ps: please direct me to the right code, i want to figure it by myself

thanks alot !

Update:

the most funniest thing is that all the things were working as i want to, the thing is that i wasn't familiar with the Test-connection "no ping" message and i thought that i'm doing something wrong loool

Comment: Change if ($mypc = $true) { to if ($mypc ***-eq*** $true) {

Comment: = is the assignment operator -eq is the equality test operator.

Comment: innocent question for you @Matt, how would that be a duplicate since WebsGhost here didn't even know what the comparison operators were? Just an opportunity to learn, I enjoy helping the community with what I can

Comment: @cet51 FWIW I think closing as a dupe is completely appropriate here, misunderstanding from OP is the same in both cases and the dupe target accepted answer contains all the relevant information (including a link to the documentation). Don't let this deter you from continuing your efforts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, `=` is the assignment operator, not a comparison operator - you're assigning the value `$true` to `$mypc`.

Use `-eq` instead:

```
if ($mypc -eq $true) {
    write-host "the $mypc is alive"
}
```

Or, since the value of `$mypc` is already a boolean you can skip the equality check:

```
if ($mypc) {
    write-host "the $mypc is alive"
}
```

Comment: Ah! Beat me to it. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close for your first script. Here is your issue:

`if ($mypc = $true)` needs to be `if ($mypc -eq $true)`

`-eq` is a comparison, when you used the `=` sign you were actually setting the variable `$mypc` to `$true`

Comment: i've added something

    $pingingonepc= Read-Host "what is the name of the pc that you want to ping?"

                Test-Connection $pingingonepc -Count 1

                if ($pingingonepc -eq "True") {
      
                write-host "the connection to the $pingingonepc is ok"
                }
                
                } else {

                write-host "the connection to the $pingingonepc is fault"
                
                }

Comment: Make sure you have the correct number of brackets everywhere. Also, when you are writing code in a comment use backtick characters (under the escape key) to enclose the code `like this`

Comment: Or better yet, edit your question and put code there. Reading code in comments (even with the markdown) is the suck...

Comment: I've got it working :)

thanks alot :)